# Weird behavior of $LINENO in a bash script using subshells in if statements

Tags: bash

Using a subshell environment in an if statement screws up my $LINENO variable. Here is a minimal reproducible code:

```
1. #!/bin/bash
2. if true ; then
3.     (echo dummy)
4. fi
5. echo "Line no:" $LINENO
```

It shows "Line no: 4" instead of 5.
Is that a normal behavior? I could not find any explanations online.
The problem occurs only if the condition is true (meaning the subshell is executed). Same problem occurs if the subshell is in a while/for loop iterating at least once.

Surprisingly the three pieces of code below work as expected:

**a) no if-then-fi**

```
1. #!/bin/bash
2. (echo dummy)
3. echo "Line no:" $LINENO
```

shows 3 as expected.

**b) no subshell**

```
1. #!/bin/bash
2. if true ; then
3.     echo dummy
4. fi
5. echo "Line no:" $LINENO
```

shows 5 as expected.

**c) nested subshells**

```
1. #!/bin/bash
2. (if true ; then
3.     (echo dummy)
4. fi)
5. echo "Line no:" $LINENO
```

shows 5 as expected.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I tried both 4.2.3 on Linux and 3.2.57 on Mac.

Comment: Nor at ideone.com: http://ideone.com/oHtUvU

Comment: I am using bash 5.0.3 on Linux 5.0.0 (default on Ubuntu 19.04)

Comment: Sounds like a bug you should report to the bash developers, it's not a problem with your script.

Comment: Thanks. I've reported it.